# JavaScript url auto-resolution in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I am running Asp.Net MVC 2.0, and I am running into a problem with my JS calls.

this is what I have in my :

```
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

Which all works fine if I am on the root level.  But if I jump up to something like:

```
Root/Items/Search/term/Page3
```

the JS doesn't run load - if I look at the source, the MVC is 'smart enough' to re-route the css, but not the Javascript:

```
<link href="../../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

I must be missing something, there has to be an easy way to do this correctly, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this sort of problems never hardcode links like this. Use helper methods instead:

```
<link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: I would possibly also add that T4MVC would be a nice idea to avoid magic strings altogether.